# Why is our query suddenly returning rows it should not (using READPAST and UPDLOCK options)?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, concurrency, queue

We have a job table that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clearing](
    [Skey] [decimal](19, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BsAcctId] [int] NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [csPk_Clearing] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Skey] ASC ) 
)
```

with a covering index like this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Status] ON [dbo].[Clearing]
(
    [Status] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Skey], [BsAcctId])
```

and we use this query to pick the next job

```
select top (1) Skey, BsAcctId, Status from Clearing with ( readpast, updlock )
  where (Clearing.Status = 'NEW')
  order by Clearing.Skey
```

(The real table has about 10 columns. They are all in the index include() clause and the select column list.)

The execution plan is very simple.  It does an index seek using IX_Status, then a top operator.  Since the index is sorted on (status, skey) the plan does not need a sort.

The table is in a database in an AlwaysOn Availability Group.  The group has 2 DB servers. (It is a test system.)

Normally this table and query work great.
So we go to apply Windows updates, and do the usual.

1. Fail over the primary to the secondary
2. Apply Windows updates on the former primary
3. Fail over back to the original primary
4. Apply Windows updates on the secondary

After the second fail over and all the worker processes get new connections to the new primary, the query starts failing in the sense that multiple processes start getting the same jobs.

The problem is load related.  With 4 worker processes running it did not happen.  But with 10 workers it happens consistently.

This is using SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.  We do not have the query store enabled to see if the execution plan was weird at some point.

Any suggestions on why the query would start failing after two fail overs?

Since the query is only using the index and not touching the table, is UPDLOCK reliable?

Update 1 - we changed the process to list the locks held by the spid (using sp_lock @@spid) just after doing the select.  For the same skey, we are seeing different KEY locks held on the IX_Status index (indid=9)

```
KEY (aad9d6e672f9)  U
KEY (154698b9131c)  U
```

Update 2 - using index hint did not help.

Update 3 - Removing order by clause in query avoided the problem.  But we have a second table with same problem that needs the order by.

Update 4 - Our worker processes maintain a db connection pool.  ODBC does not tell us when a fail over happens, so connections to an old primary stay in the pool until we try to use them and they fail.  We suspect after we failover DB1 -> DB2 -> DB1, then old connections to DB1 might not fail like they should.  We made a change to close all pooled connections after any one connection is lost, and this seems to have avoided the problem.  (SQL Server ODBC added a "Connection Resiliency" feature that is fueling this suspicion.)

Answer (score 5):

### Getting the same row from different indexes

As David mentions in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241301/6141), you can get the same row from multiple sessions if you happen to access that row via different indexes.

The `UPDLOCK` hint only applies to the specific access method. Having a nonclustered index row `U` locked does not prevent another query acquiring a `U` lock on a *different* index (including the clustered index, if any).

Running these two queries (with index hints) from different sessions results in the same row being returned:

```
-- Session 1
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT TOP (1) Skey, BsAcctId, Status 
FROM dbo.Clearing WITH(READPAST, UPDLOCK, INDEX(2))
WHERE ([Status] = 'NEW')
ORDER BY Skey;

-- Session 2
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT TOP (1) Skey, BsAcctId, Status 
FROM dbo.Clearing WITH(READPAST, UPDLOCK, INDEX(1))
WHERE ([Status] = 'NEW')
ORDER BY Skey;
```

After the failover, new execution plans will be compiled for incoming queries - so this could explain why you ended up with the new behavior after the failover.  As David also said, you could force the index to avoid this problem.

As a side note, you should also use a `ROWLOCK` hint, since `READPAST` can only skip locks taken at the row granularity.

### Getting different rows in the same session due to concurrency

You also mentioned this:

> The problem is load related. With 4 worker processes running it did not happen. But with 10 workers it happens consistently.

So it sounds like the failover was not the only thing that changed - you also increased concurrency on the application side of things.

I tried loading up your table / index with some data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Clearing
    ([Status])
SELECT TOP 100
    'NEW'
FROM master.dbo.spt_values;

INSERT INTO dbo.Clearing
    ([Status])
SELECT TOP 10000
    'COMPLETE'
FROM master.dbo.spt_values v1
    CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values v2;
```

Then I loaded up SQL Query Stress with your query, set it to run on 10 threads at once, every 100 ms:

[image: screenshot of SQL Query Stress settings]

While that was running, I periodically ran the same query with `EXEC sp_lock @spid1 = @my_spid;` tacked on to the end in SSMS.  If I run the `SELECT` query in the same session multiple times (without rolling back), I can get multiple locks held by that session:

[image: screenshot of SSMS results with two U locks]

Which you can see using the `%%lockres%%` predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Clearing WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(2)) WHERE %%lockres%% = '(36aaaeef6267)';
SELECT * FROM dbo.Clearing WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX(2)) WHERE %%lockres%% = '(84d6be32a10d)';
```

[image: screenshot of SSMS showing IDs 9 and 11 locked]

Without much concurrency, you'll generally get the same row if you run that `SELECT` more than once in the session.  But with other queries taking and releasing locks all the time, it's easily possible to get different rows.  So make sure you are not depending on the `SELECT` returning the same ID twice (we don't have the whole context of your workload, so this is just speculation / FYI).

### Unexpected locking behavior

It's can be unsafe to depend solely on specific locks to be taken.  Consider an optimization described in this blog post from Paul White (or another one like it): [The Case of the Missing Shared Locks](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/11/read-committed-shared-locks-and-rollbacks.html)

The post outlines a situation where a row protected by an X lock can still be read by `SELECT` queries:

> SQL Server contains an optimization that allows it to avoid taking row-level shared (S) locks in the right circumstances. Specifically, it can skip shared locks if there is no risk of reading uncommitted data without them.

### Related reading:

- [Using tables as Queues](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) by Remus Rusanu
- [When READPAST Doesn’t Read Past](https://erikdarlingdata.com/2019/04/when-readpast-doesnt-read-past/) by Erik Darling

Answer (score 5):

You've got two different indexes that can satisfy that query.  So two queries, running two different plans could each lock a key on a different index.

Try forcing the index in the query.

Comment: We will try this.  The table has the clustered index and two secondary indexes.  Once we saw the same job given to 6 different SPID's at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

> Lock hints ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK, AND XLOCK that acquire row-level locks
> may place locks on index keys rather than the actual data rows. For
> example, if a table has a nonclustered index, and a SELECT statement
> using a lock hint is handled by a covering index, a lock is acquired
> on the index key in the covering index rather than on the data row in
> the base table.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Lock%20hints%20ROWLOCK,the%20base%20table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Lock%20hints%20ROWLOCK,the%20base%20table).